# Remove certain words when importing from text file to ListView in visual studio

Tags: vb.net

How do i remove certain words from a txt file when importing to a ListView on button click?

Currently I have 3 columns and each column is separated by "|"

```
Dim Path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Dim AllItems As String

Try
AllItems = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path)

Dim ItemLines As New TextBox
ItemLines.Text = AllItems

 For Each line As String In ItemLines.Lines
      Dim List1() As String = line.Split("|")

      Dim ItemName As String = List1(0)
      Dim SubItem1 As String = List2(1)
      Dim SubItem2 As String = List3(2)


 Dim Item As New ListViewItem(ItemName)

            Item.SubItems.Add(SubItem1)
            Item.SubItems.Add(SubItem2)
            Item.SubItems.Add(SubItem2)

 ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {Item})
```

The text file contains the following words:
Hello: 500 |  World: 20 | Age: 30 |

I want to Remove the words

Hello: World:  Age:

and only display 
500 20 30
in the ListView for each of its following columns

Comment: If your text file contains, "Hello: 500 World: 20 Age: 30" how are you splitting by "|"?  Are you only interested in getting numbers from the file and displaying the numbers in three columns?

Comment: Yes im only interested in getting the numbers

Comment: The text file actually looks like this Hello: 500 | World: 20 | Age: 30 |

Comment: im still having issues sorry...
i did the following:

For Each line As String In ItemLines.Lines
                ItemLines.Lines.IndexOf(piece.SubString(piece.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim())

                Dim linePieces = line.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)



                For Each piece As String In linePieces

  
  Dim ItemName As String = linePieces(0)
                Dim SubItem1 As String = linePieces(1)

Comment: Try Dim ItemName As String = List1(0).SubString(List1(0).IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();  ...  And then do the same for the other two SubItems.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I really appreciate it.  I just have to figure out why some of the text numbers is repeating more than once, for example, 500 30 20 is repeating 2 more additional times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of your data is

```
AAAAA: ### | AAAAA: ### | AAAAA: ### |
```

And you're already splitting by the pipe, as you're iterating through the array you can do a `Substring()` using the `IndexOf()` of the ":".  This will get you just the numbers after the semicolon of each array element.

Something like:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim line = "Hello: 500 | World: 20 | Age: 30 |"
        Dim linePieces = line.Split(new Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each piece As String in linePieces
            Console.WriteLine(piece.SubString(piece.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim())
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
500
20
30
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fkwL64)

Comment: @taji01 You should be able to apply the Substring() with IndexOf() on the three lines you have right after your Split() line.

Comment: @taji01 If my answer was helpful to solve your question, kindly click the check mark to my answer so your question is solved.

Comment: Hopefully I clicked on the correct check mark. Thanks again